# Escape special characters in a std::string

Tags: c++, string, stl

I have a std::string object. The context should be passed to a log function that accepts the parameter in format style similar to `printf`. But there are limitations in the storage for parameters. Only a few bytes can be used for parameters.

The string is read from a file and I can't make any assumptions except that it only contains readable characters. The function would interpret the string and take special care for the '%' character. But since this is not a real format string I need to escape the percent character.

*Edit:* The log function is limited in parameter and capabilities size so it's impossible to use `"%s"` as the format string and the string as parameter. Therefore I need to convert the string. So `log("%s", foo.c_str())` is impossible.

How do duplicate all percent signs in a `std::string`?

```
std::string foo = "got 7%\n";
```

`foo` should be "got 7%%\n" after escaping.

Comment: Any comments for downvoting?

Comment: You don't need to escape the string at all, as you shouldn't be passing it in as a format string to begin with. Use a separate format string of `"%s"` and pass in the string as its parameter, eg: `log("%s", foo.c_str())` or `log("%.*s", foo.size(), foo.c_str())`

Comment: The getline() function doesn't perform any processing on characters it reads, so you don't have to escape anything. But your question is far from clear.

Comment: @NeilButterworth As you could have been read in the question the content is from an external source. So you should not assume the the read function, e.g. `getline` would be responsible for the content.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The special log function *is* limited and can be used with `"%s"`.

Comment: @harper if the function doesn't accept something as simple as `"%s"` as a format string then it is not a true printf-style function

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes you're right, it's not exactly a true printf-style function. That's why I wrote `similar to` instead of `like` in the question.

Comment: If you want to know how to duplicate every occurrence of a given character in a C++ `std::string`, you should have asked just that... all the rest is noise then, distracting from the actual question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to escape the string if the function is a true printf-style function. Do not pass in the string as a format string, use a separate format string of `"%s"` and pass in the string as its parameter, eg:

```
log("%s", foo.c_str());
```

or

```
log("%.*s", foo.size(), foo.c_str());
```

If that is not an option, then you need to replace the `%` characters manually in a loop, eg:

```
std::string::size_type i = foo.find('%');
while (i != std::string::npos)
{
    foo.replace(i, 1, "%%");
    i = foo.find('%', i+2);
}
log(foo.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

Never pass non-program stored/generated strings as format strings.

Instead pass `"%s"` as the format string and pass the string to print as an argument.

Comment: As you can read i *want* to *build in my program* a format string based on the input. If I would pass these string without treatment I wouldn't ask. `"%s"` is excluded in the question for reason.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that looks a bit more elegant than that in Remys fine answer.

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <logutil.h>

std::regex percent(L"%");

std::string s;
// ... get a line from file ...

s = std::regex_replace(s, percent, L"%%");
log(s.c_str());
```

I didn't check the performance, since this is not important in my use case.