# Retrieve CString file path from XML file

Tags: c++, xml, mfc, filepath, c-strings

I have an XML file with many values and a working C++ function that can retrieve these values

Two of these values are:

1. A file path such as: `"C:\foo1\foo2"` and
2. A file name: `"foo3.txt"`

Combining these together, they would become `"C:\foo1\foo2\foo3.txt"`

However, while trying to set a `CString` to save a file path, it will give an error because using the character, `\`, in a string is not allowed due to string notation and its interaction with the `\` character.

I am using MFC, and I know WIN32 allows you to create a file path with `/` instead of `\`, so: `"C:/foo1/foo2/foo3.txt"` would work. I tested this in Windows Explorer and it worked.

I would like to collect the file path from XML file, but when it comes in, it will have `\` instead of `/` in its file path, meaning it will not be possible to replace the character (the string coming in will have an error already due to XML not having a problem with the `\` character.

How do I safely retrieve the path as a `CString`, ideally while converting any `\` character to a `/` character.

Comment: Yes backslash is a special character and needs to be escaped. You will has a similar issue with the quotation mark and % sign. \ to \\      " to \"     % to %%. I'll write some code as to how to do this

Comment: thank you :) I did not consider these other special characters, by quotation mark do you mean ' or ", I think ' is allowed in file names but not "

Comment: *"ideally while converting any \ character to a /"* - There's nothing ideal about that. The path separator on Windows is a backslash character. All this conversion would accomplish is limit its applicability by now relying on the system to reverse the conversion. Sometimes it does, and other times it doesn't. The prime candidate here being if you wish to use pathnames that [exceed 260 characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation).

Comment: Maybe a bit late (for commenting on a question with an accepted answer) but I think the answers (and the question) are actually WRONG! How do you get an error "while trying to set a CString", and how do you "set" the `CString`? If you are just concatenating the strings, the result should be OK, as a string variable (char[] or CString) can contain the '\' char normally (it's not an escape marker), and characters are not escaped. What needs to be escaped is C/C++ string literals (and strings in JSON files). If you "set" the `CString` by assigning a string literal, yes, it must be escaped.

Comment: Furthermore, XML doesn't use escape sequences like ' \\', '\n' etc, the escape sequences in XML are `&quot;`, `&apos;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`, corresponding to `"`, `'`, `<`, `>`, `&` respectively.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=manually-xml-escape-characters
The "parser" code posted should be changed to convert those character sequences instead.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I see, so you mean if I import the string with a \ character, there is no issue and it can be used as is, but if I define a string myself in the code, ie hardcode it, then there will be an issue ? I will need to use the a string vector of file paths to collect a bunch of files and put them together into a large .zip file .

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou also would you recommend using CString or string ?

Comment: As currently asked, the question is impossible to answer. Both of the answers you have received so far are *very* likely wrong, and do not address the core issue. It is extremely likely that none of this has anything to do with XML, and it's all about your code failing to construct a string a character literal holding a backslash character. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: It's a matter of language spec, ie how string constants must be written in C/C++ source files. A string literal of "C:\\foo1" will put a value of `C:\foo1` in the .obj file (7 printable chars plus the terminating null), while "C:\foo1" would be wrong, because `\f` would translate as a form-feed char. Take a look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape). Finally, you have a debugger at your disposal (you could also print or trace them), so play a little bit with it, it won't be hard to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Now I'm not familiar with the "CString" class you are refering to. Googling the API documentation  just has the standard c style char array format commands, so I'm going to assume rightly or wrongly cstring is a char array.

The fact we are going to need to use an object that is not resizable means we either

1. Need to use the heap, which will be slow, and can leak memory if the memory isn't deleted later
2. Allow a maximum string length and accept it will be truncated if below this

Heap example (NOTE: I'm not using smart pointers as I assume they don't have access to them, else you'd just std::string and not do this.)

```
char* escapeString(const char* data, unsigned int length){
    //multiplying by 1.5 means this could still truncate, 
    //but I'm making an educated guess it's not all bad characters.
    const int newLen = (length + 1) * 1.5;
    char* escaped = new char[newLen + 1];
    
    unsigned int index = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < length && i < newLen; i++){
        if(data[i] == '\\' || data[i] == '\"'){
            escaped[index++] = '\\';
        }
        else if(data[i] == '%'){
            escaped[index++] = '%';
        }
        //else anything else you want to escape
        escaped[index++] = data[i];
    }

    //Make sure a null string is null terminatedescaped
    escaped[index] = '\0';
    return escaped;
}


int main() {
    const char* stringWithBadChars = "I\"m not a %%good \\string";
    
    char* escapedString = escapeString(stringWithBadChars, strlen(stringWithBadChars));

    std::cout << escapedString;

    delete [] escapedString;
    return 0;
}
```

If we do this on the stack instead it would be a lot faster, but we are limited by the size of the buffer we give, and the size of the buffer in the function. We will return a bool if either fails.

```
bool escapeString(char* data, unsigned int length){
    const int newLen = 1000;
    char escaped[1001];
    
    unsigned int index = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < length && i < newLen; i++){
        if(data[i] == '\\' || data[i] == '\"'){
            escaped[index++] = '\\';
        }
        else if(data[i] == '%'){
            escaped[index++] = '%';
        }
        escaped[index++] = data[i];
    }

    //Make sure a null string is null terminatedescaped
    memcpy(data, escaped, index);
    escaped[index] = '\0';

    return index < length && index < 1000;
}
```

You could probably get even more efficiency using memmov rather than copy it character by character. Doing it this way you also wouldn't need the second char array.

Comment: thank you, how do you mean "else you'd just std::string and not do this" ? I could try using std::string and then converting it to a cstring after retrieving the data and converting any \ chars to / chars. Does std::string offer an easier solution ?

Comment: std::string is a nice container that manages char arrays. In the first example you could replace the signature with std::string escapeString(const char* data). Then just create a std::string in the function std::string outString = data, then do something along the lines of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51458105/escape-special-characters-in-a-stdstring

Comment: hmm but this is assuming that the char array is accepted by c++ as a string and is just replacing the bad chars with chars I want, correct ? however the problem I am having is that the xml file string has bad chars which means it cannot be loaded into a c++ string in the first place, no ?

Comment: Yeah, really depends on your limitations. The code above is the c style way of doing it and should work pretty much no matter what. Just remember if you use the heap example, you must delete it at some point or you will leak memory

Comment: @hus There are no *"bad chars"* that couldn't *"be loaded into a c++ string"*. A `std::string` or `CString` can store **any** sequence of values. Neither one attempts to interpret the data it holds, and neither one requires that one or more values are set aside as a sentinel. You have mis-identified your issue, and are now seeking a solution to what you believe to be your problem (which, in reality, isn't a problem at all).

Answer (score 1):

`CString` reserves some special characters. Have a look at the [`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class?view=msvc-170#format) command as an example. The linked documentation refers you to: [Format specification syntax: `printf` and `wprintf` functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=msvc-170).

The `\` is used as mentioned in the comments to indicate a special character. For example:

- `\t` will insert a **tab** character.
- `\"` will insert a **double quote** character.

So when it hits the `\` it expects the next character to be one of the special ones. Therefore, when you actually need a backslash, you use `\\`.

The linked article does explain about `%` but not the slash. However, tt is exactly the same with `%` because it too has special meaning. So you would use `%%` when you want the percent sign.

Comment: *"`CString` reserves some special characters."* - It doesn't. It merely manages a sequence of `char` or `wchar_t` values. Any value is allowed to appear anywhere, any number of times. Reserved characters are a feature of *parsers*. For example: C uses `"` as the delimiter for string literals, `printf` assigns special meaning to `%` in a format string, URLs do the same for `?` or `#`, and XML for e.g. `<` or `>`. To encode those they need to be [escaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence). This is specific to each protocol. `CString` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @IInspectable I getcha. So I didn’t explain it with the right phrasing. And clearly it is not limited to CString as I linked to the other functions which are not CString derived. At the end of the day it boils down to needing two \\. But thanks for your comment.

Comment: That's not what it boils down to, no. The key point is that *parsers* have specific rules for processing input. When handing a string literal to a C compiler, you'll have to escape, among others, the backslash character. But this question isn't about C string literals. It's about XML, and in XML you [do not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/1889329) need to escape a backslash character.

Comment: @IInspectable So why tag it MFC and C++. Anyway, I offer my answer as is because he asked about combining two values to build a path. And he was using CString. I say no more on the subject.

Comment: What I would say is that using the bespoke path combining functions would be best anyway as it is designed for the purpose.

Comment: And I never said the paths need two slashes. But if you are gonna manually build path by adding a path and slash and file name yourself then you need two slashes. Xml doesn’t matter. It is two variables being stitched together. But you know all this as you are more knowledgeable than me.